# ¿Por qué cada vez que setInterval hace un ciclo me devuelve cada unos de los resultados de todos los ciclos hechos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, setinterval, puppeteer

Tengo un bot scrapper que usa discordjs, puppeteer y nodejs, lo que ocurre es que en el código tengo un setInterval para que haga el ciclo infinito pero cada que hace un ciclo, este me muestra cada unos de los resultados de todos los ciclos y yo solo quiero mostrar el último resultado.

Código:

```
        (async () => {
setInterval(async () => {
    const URL = url
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(URL, { 'waitUntil' : 'networkidle2' })
    let jobsListing= await page.evaluate(()=>{
        var a = document.getElementById("task-listing-datatable").getAttribute("data-tasks");
        var ar = eval(a);

        var keyword = ['asdad', 'asdakdada', 'mama', 'Duplicate Fashion Product Identification Task'];
        for(let i=0; i<ar.length; i++){
            for(let j=0; j<keyword.length; j++){
                if(ar[i][1] === keyword[j]){  
                    let job =   (`${ar[i][1]}`);
                    return (`${ar[i][0]} ${ar[i][1]} Paga ${ar[i][3]} Tareas: ${ar[i][5]}`);
            }
        }
    }

    });
    console.log(`==== first login ====`)
    console.log(`==================`)
    console.log(jobsListing)
    client.on('message', msg =>{

            if (msg.content === 'ping') {
                msg.reply(jobsListing);

        }

    });

    await page.reload();


    console.log(`after reload`)

}, 8000)
})();
```

Y así muestra el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema que se puede apreciar es que tienes un listener que se instancia cada vez que el intervalo corre, en consecuencia se ejecutaran tantos listeners de client.on('message'... como intervals se ejecuten, trata de separar el intervalo del listener y nos avisas, suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que estás añadiendo un *listener* en cada *ciclo*:

```
setInterval(async () => {

  ... //tu código

  client.on('message', msg => {

    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
      msg.reply(jobsListing);
    }
  });
},8000);
```

Así que cuando se recibe un ping, tienes N *event handlers* (se añade uno cada 8 segundos) que reciben el mismo mensaje, con lo que obtienes N respuestas idénticas.

No tengo claro qué hace tu código, así que no te puedo dar la solución al problema. Podría ser asegurarte de que sólo haya un *event handler* escuchando los *pings* y gestionaras una lista de respuestas pendientes, por ejemplo.